# Enter Showroom Button in A-Frame

Tags: javascript, html, aframe

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<title>A-Frame</title>
<script src="//aframe.io/releases/0.7.1/aframe.min.js"></script>
<style>
   a-scene{
     z-index: -1;
   }
   .container{
     position:absolute;
     width:100%;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     margin-top: 15%;
   }
   .button{
     font-weight: bold;
     background-color: limegreen;
      padding: 10px;
     margin: 24px 0 0 0;
   }

</style>

</head>
<body>
<div id="container" class="container">
    <a class="button" id="start_experience" href="#">start experience</a>
</div>
<a-scene>
  <a-box position="-1 0.5 -3" rotation="0 45 0" color="#4CC3D9"></a-box>
</a-scene>
 <script>
  var startExperienteBtn = document.getElementById('start_experience');

   startExperienteBtn.onclick = function(){
   document.getElementById('container').outerHTML = '';
   document.getElementsByTagName('a-scene')[0].style.zIndex = 'auto';
  };
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to make a Enter Room button. And that button must be static not dynamic. And before scene should hide. It will appear after clicking that button. If I click that, then only goes to VR showroom. My code if I click it's not working. What's the issue?

Comment: The question is unclear. Could you try reformulating the question?

Comment: When your script is run the `start_experience` element doesn't yet exist. Try moving your script to the end of the document - just before the `</body>` tag.

Comment: @Turnip Yes I changed that but that does not work.

Comment: @Damien https://cecropia.github.io/thehallaframe/
Check this. If you click enter experience, it goes to museum. I want to make like this. If I click then only goes to showroom.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide the scene UNTIL someone clicks the button, then you can switch the `a-scene`'s css `display` attribute from:

`display: none` to `display:block` on click.

You can check it out [here](https://jsfiddle.net/qcLyud1b/4/).